# Smaato RTB error message

Tags: python, json, smaato

Error message:
BidResponseTooLongException
Context information:

bid response length = 14500
max length = 6144

I got this error while tested on smaato rtb website (http://dspportal.smaato.net/).
When I tested this response in my local machine by self created Ad-request it's response is exactly same like openrtb document's response .But when i tested on smaato rtb it gives error as above.can anybody help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet would be that Smaato, like any web service which takes security concerns seriously limits the length of incoming data. 6k seems like a reasonable number to limit the length of bid response. I actually never stumbled upon a case where bid response with single ad slot ([Smaato requirement](http://dspportal.smaato.net/documentation#specLimitations)) could not fit 2000 characters in length.